# Issue with deep learning model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm a beginner to deep learning and machine learning in general, so I'm sure I'm making some silly mistakes but anyway.

I have a relatively small dataset of around 70 images of various people, and I'm trying to create a deep net to guess their ages. It may be an issue to do with the size/lack of variety in the dataset, but my final activation ends up consisting of an array with literally all the same values.

For example, say the dataset goes [10, 23, 72, 35...], my model is performing gradient descent in a way that basically finds an average of all of them, so the final activation would be [33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, ...]. Apologies for the trouble, but would anyone be able to quickly troubleshoot my code to spot any super obvious errors that I've made? Or is it something outside my control, like a lack of variety in the dataset? For reference, I'm not using a framework because I wanted to try implementing it from scratch first.

I'm using MSE for my cost function, tanh as the activation function for my layers, and a linear function for my output layer. I think I'm using Xavier Glorot initialisation successfully. Below are some of the functions where I think an error has probably crept in.

```
#Propagation Stuff
 
    def __forward_prop(self):
        A = self.X
        for l in range(1, self.n):
            Z = np.dot(self.W[l-1], A) + self.b[l-1]
            A = self.g[l](Z)
            self.cache[l] = [Z, A]
 
    def __gradient_descent(self):
        dA = 2 * (self.cache[-1][1] - self.Y)
        for l in range(self.n - 1, 0, -1):
            dZ = dA * self.gprime[l](self.cache[l][0])
            dW = (1/self.m) * np.dot(dZ, self.cache[l-1][1].T)
            dB = (1/self.m) * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
            self.W[l-1] = self.W[l-1] - (self.lr * dW)
            self.b[l-1] = self.b[l-1] - (self.lr * dB)
            dA = np.dot(self.W[l-1].T, dZ)
 
 
 
#Some of the Initialisation Stuff
 
self.W = []
        for l in range(1, self.n):
            xgb = sqrt(6)/sqrt(n_sizes[l] + n_sizes[l-1])
            self.W.append(np.array([u(-xgb, xgb, n_sizes[l-1]) for _ in range(n_sizes[l])]))
 
if g is None:
    self.g = [np.tanh for _ in range(self.n - 1)]
    self.g.append(lambda x: x)
    self.gprime = [self.tanh_derivative for _ in range(self.n - 1)]
    self.gprime.append(lambda x: 1)
else:
    self.g = g
    self.gprime = gprime
```

Incidentally, if anyone has an idea of what may be going wrong and wants to check other functions in my code, please just let me know.

EDIT: I have since done some research and found that I really should be using data labels and an accuracy metric instead. Working on it now.